# what is the way of Mybatis to bind mapper interface with the corresponding Mapper xml file

Tags: spring-mybatis

How does mybatis bind mapper xml file with the corresponding mapper interface.

Mapper xml namespace <-> full path Mapper interface

Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This is explained in the [getting started](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/getting-started.html) page.